# Chamar um método equivalente a uma string

Tags: c#, string, unity3d, método, reflexão

Considere a seguinte classe:

```
public class AnimationManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] Enemies;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D o) {
        if (o.tag == "Player")
            foreach(GameObject Enemy in Enemies)
                //Eval(Enemy.transform.name + "Animation();");
    }

    void MacacoAnimation(){
        //...
    }
}
```

O que pretendo é quando o objecto colidir com o player, o script executa um método equivalente ao nome do objecto concatenado com a string "Animation".

Veja onde inserir o codigo comentado:

```
Eval(Enemy.transform.name + "Animation();");
```

Aqui executaria o método, mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: O que é esse `Enemy.transform.name`?

Comment: Enemy.transform.name retorna uma string com o nome do objecto do jogo.

Comment: Ta com toda a cara que deveria ter uma interface no lugar dessa implementação concreta de objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aconselho fazer isto com métodos delegados e não usar *string* para definir a chamada do método. Parece que você está usando um evento para disparar eventos, só que do jeito errado.

Mas vou te dar uma resposta porque pode ser que não consiga fazer desta forma:

```
var nomeMetodo = Enemy.transform.name + "Animation";
var Metodo = this.GetType().GetMethod(nomeMetodo);
Metodo.Invoke(this, null);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VvVNNY). E [no **.NET FIddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IWDosH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/Invoke.cs).

Uma otimização seria:

```
var Metodo = typeof(AnimationManager).GetMethod(nomeMetodo);
```

Não sei se isto resolve totalmente o que precisa mas é o que deu sem um contexto maior.

Obviamente que se a *string* contiver um nome que não pode gerar um método válido, vai dar exceção.

Comment: Como seria com métodos delegados? Poderia dar um exemplo? Obrigado.

Comment: Sai do foco da pergunta e só conseguiria vendo um contexto maior da aplicação. Mas pode ser que não consiga mudar a aplicação para resolver isto.

Comment: Então não seria uma boa prática utilizar strings? Sei que sai do foco da pergunta, mas foi só uma ideia e acabei perguntando como se faz sem saber se deveria.

Comment: Para isto, não, tanto quanto possível.

Comment: A ideia é legal, mas não acho que é uma boa escolha pro AP (e nem sei se não daria outros problemas na Unity, já que ela faz um controle das invocações por causa do *framerate*). E outra coisa, (apesar de ele não deixar claro) ele não quer executar esse método no `this` (que é a classe `AnimationManager`), e sim na instância `Enemy` (uma instância de uma classe que ele não menciona, mas que é manipulada por meio da classe básica `GameObject`).

Comment: Eu respondi o que dava para responder com a informação que tinha e em cima do que ele pediu. Eu não fari isto com certeza. Eu vi que todo o *design* tá ruim. Esse método não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Já percebi que foi uma péssima ideia e estou a utilizar outra solução. Entretanto como a sua resposta resolve a questão, marquei como certa. Obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Comment: Expliquei o que pretendo aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83690/como-organizar-o-c%C3%B3digo-para-que-seja-reaproveitado penso que assim fica mais fácil entender.

Answer (score 3):

Na Unity, a forma de executar um método de outro script é a seguinte:

```
Objeto.GetComponent<NomeDaClasseDoScript>().NomeDoMetodo();
```

Ou

```
Objeto.GetComponent("NomeDaClasseDoScript").NomeDoMetodo();
```

A segunda forma tem desvantagens em desempenho (porque precisa fazer a reflexão em um sentido parecido ao que o @Maniero já te descreveu), mas funciona para o que você quer. Assim, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

1. Crie diferentes *scripts* ao invés de diferentes métodos em um único *script*. Cada *script* vai ter o nome que você está definindo (em `transform.name`). E *todos eles* terão o mesmo método `animation` (claro, cada um fazendo o que tem que fazer de forma diferente).
2. Execute o método da seguinte forma: `Enemy.GetComponent(Enemy.transform.name).Animation();`. Note que isso pode gerar erros durante a execução do seu jogo se o *script* com o nome `Enemy.transform.name` não existir!

Dito isso, eu gostaria de mencionar que eu entendi o que você quer fazer mas não entendi *exatamente* por que você quer fazer isso. Você está centralizando o controle da animação em uma classe chamada `AnimationManager`, quando poderia ter deixado isso a cargo da classe de cada inimigo (o inimigo também pode detectar a colisão e, sozinho, executar sua animação). Do ponto de vista da orientação a objetos isso é uma escolha bem ruim, pois cria um acoplamento desnecessário e certamente vai dificultar a sua manutenção futura.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Com certeza essa é a melhor forma é a que menos consome na hora de rodar.
Deixar que o prefab(e classe) do inimigo cuide das animações é o que está mais coerente com a forma de desenvolver no Unity.
Eu recomendo que ao invés de chamar um método, use as funções do próprio Unity e determine parâmetros para cada animação que você quer, desta forma você pode determinar cada uma delas mudando um boleano ou disparando um trigger.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fotMn6x7aoU

Comment: @Nils e Luiz, para cada inimigo tenho a animação normal gerada através dos sprites (frame by frame do unity) e depois tenho outo tipo de animação que é a deslocação do inimigo, por exemplo, mover para cima e para baixo, isso faço com código por causa do boxcollider2d, para poder movimenta-lo também, porém essa ação de ir para cima e para baixo não é especifica do inimigo e queria reutiliza-la em outros, por isso centralizei em um único ficheiro. Já percebi que isso foi uma péssima ideia. :)

Comment: Vou criar uma pergunta mais específica e demonstrar o que realmente pretendo e incluir imagens, fica mais fácil perceber! Obrigado pelo vosso tempo.

Comment: Expliquei o que pretendo aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83690/como-organizar-o-c%C3%B3digo-para-que-seja-reaproveitado penso que assim fica mais fácil entender.