# Como organizar o código para que seja reaproveitado

Tags: c#, unity3d

Considere o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, o prefab (vermelho) é constituído por 3 elementos:

1. O `sprite` (que é o chão, os quadradinhos castanho e o tubo verde)
2. O `enemy` (rosa) que é um outro prefab
3. O empty `GameObject` (azul)

Apenas para entender o contexto, o jogo funciona assim: a cada "x" segundos adiciono um novo prefab no do cenário, produzindo assim um cenário infinito (tenho vários prefab's e a imagem acima contém apenas 1 para exemplo). O player vai para cima e para baixo e não pode encostar no inimigo.

A parte de movimentar o prefab, de colidir com o inimigo e morrer, etc... está feito e a funcionar e não é esse o problema, por isso não inseri aqui códigos.

O que pretendo é quando o `player` (laranja) colidir com o `GameObject` (azul) o `Enemy` (rosa) vá para cima e para baixo em looping.

Para entender o porquê de cada elemento dentro do prefab: como tenho vários prefabs (vermelho) de larguras diferentes e inimigos (rosa) diferentes em posições diferentes, o empty `GameObject` (azul) serve apenas para indicar ao inimigo que deve iniciar a sua animação quando o `player` colidir com ele, assim tenho mais flexibilidade para criar novos prefabs.

Exitem 2 tipos de animações para cada inimigo: a que fiz através da aba `Animation` e é especifica para cada tipo de inimigo e a animação compartilhada, por exemplo, ir um pouco para cima e um pouco para baixo em looping, ou ir para a esquerda e para a direita em looping, etc...

A segunda animação pode ser utilizada em vários inimigos e pretendo fazer por código para que o boxcollider também se movimente, o que não é possível utilizando o `Animation` (até onde eu sei).

A minha dúvida é como implementar o que descrevi acima? Como organizar o código para que seja reaproveitado?

Sei implementar a relação entre 2 objectos, quando um colide com o outro, porém estamos a falar de uma colisão que terá efeito em um terceiro objecto.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eu presumo que você esteja usando o `GameObject` vazio apenas como "ativador" pra animação do inimigo por motivos de desempenho (isto é, pra evitar que ele já venha animado desde a instanciação do prefab, mesmo com o avatar do jogador ainda bem longe do inimigo). Isso é uma boa coisa a se fazer, mas ainda assim seria interessante colocar esse controle no escopo do próprio inimigo.

É *mais ou menos* próximo do que prega a [orientação a agentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80614/o-que-%C3%A9-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-agentes): cada entidade "inteligente" no seu jogo tem seus próprios objetivos, e por isso toda a programação desses objetivos faz mais sentido no escopo do agente. Pense assim: o seu inimigo começa ou para de se animar porque ele tem como objetivo atacar o avatar do jogador. Então, na *fantasia do jogo*, ele não está se movendo ou parando por questões de desempenho (ainda que no mundo real isso seja extremamente útil!), mas apenas porque ele é capaz de *detectar por si só* a presença do jogador.

Sendo assim, eu faria da seguinte forma:

- Não usaria um GameObject vazio como no seu exemplo pra detectar o jogador, mas sim usaria um *trigger* (o colisor é mais voltado à física) em toda a área do prefab (vermelho). Esse *trigger* capturaria os dois eventos de entrada ([onTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) e [onTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html)) para indicar à todos os inimigos existentes no prefab que o jogador entrou e saiu dessa área de ameaça (*threat area*).
- O script/classe dos inimigos seria herdado de um script/classe-base, de forma que você pudesse invocar um método abstrato a partir dos eventos de colisão do *trigger*. Assim, cada inimigo poderia implementar o seu próprio comportamento (isto é, cada um poderia fazer como mais bem entender com a informação de que o inimigo entrou e/ou saiu da área de ameaça).

### Código de Exemplo

Classe básica do Inimigo:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyBase : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool playerNear;

    public bool isPlayerNear { 
        get { return playerNear; }
        protected set { playerNear = value; }
    }

    public void playerEnteredThreat ()
    {
        isPlayerNear = true;
    }

    public void playerExitedThreat ()
    {
        isPlayerNear = false;
    }
}
```

Classe específica de um inimigo qualquer, herdada da classe básica:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemySpecific : EnemyBase {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (isPlayerNear) {
            GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            Debug.Log ("Player esta proximo! Distancia: " + Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position));
        }

    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso (detecção das colisões e passagem de mensagem para a classe abstrata do inimigo - este é o código que vai no trigger; eu só referenciei um inimigo nele, mas dá na mesma no seu caso):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Teste : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject enemy;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider oOther) {
        if (oOther.tag == "Player")
            enemy.GetComponent<EnemyBase> ().playerEnteredThreat ();
    } 

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider oOther) {
        if (oOther.tag == "Player")
            enemy.GetComponent<EnemyBase> ().playerExitedThreat ();
    }
}
```

### Explicação do Código de Exemplo

1. A classe do inimigo herda de uma classe base, que contém todo o código para receber as indicações de entrada/saída do colisor/trigger (use o que preferir, mas se não tem intenção de ter resultados físicos, trigger é mais indicado). Esses valores são reutilizados pela classe filha (via uma propriedade que eu criei chamada `isPlayerNear`, mas você poderia *sobrescrever* os métodos de notificação se assim desejasse.
2. O script que está *de fato* adicionado ao objeto do inimigo é o `EnemySpecific`, mas note como no código do trigger ele faz o seguinte:

`enemy.GetComponent<EnemyBase> ().playerEnteredThreat ();`

Ou seja, ele referencia o que quer que esteja no inimigo por meio da classe abstrata. Como todos os inimigos vão herdar dessa classe (e, consequentemente, ter em sua interface o método `playerEnteredThreat`, seja ele o original da classe base ou um reescrito na classe filha), isso garantidamente funciona. E permite que o trigger avise de forma genérica, e cada implementação de inimigo faz com isso o que bem desejar.

### Concluindo

Essa abordagem tem a vantagem de que facilita a criação de inimigos com comportamentos distintos, de forma independente da detecção da movimentação do jogador. Hoje, por exemplo, você praticamente só detecta a aproximação do jogador. Mas imagina que o jogo tá quase pronto e então o projetista do jogo (o game designer) chegasse pra você e solicitasse uma "pequena alteração": ele quer que se o jogador consiga se desvencilhar do inimigo e se afaste, o inimigo ative uma arma de tiro único de longo alcance (sei lá, cuspa uma semente explosiva, por exemplo). Nesse caso, você vai precisar *também* detectar o afastamento do jogador, e com a arquitetura atual isso será bem mais difícil (talvez você terá que incluir um novo `GameObject` vazio no final, e mais código duplicado pra fazer o mesmo que já faz).

Outra vantagem de saber que o avatar do jogador está na área de ameaça é que a "inteligência" do inimigo pode mudar sua atitude *do ponto de vista da observação*. É muito fácil cada inimigo no jogo ter uma referência ao objeto do jogador e calcular a distância euclidiana de si até ele. O problema é que isso tem custo computacional bem grande. Imagina cada inimigo em um conjunto de 100 fazendo esses cálculos (que envolvem raiz quadrada, uma operação bem custosa) a cada quadro. Usando a indicação da presença ou ausência do jogador na área de ameaça, esse tipo de cálculo pode ser realizado com um bom desempenho *apenas pelos inimigos que estão na mesma área de ameaça do jogador*. Pode parecer bobagem, mas isso facilita a implementação futura de comportamentos mais complexos com um desempenho melhor. Por exemplo, um inimigo poderia intencionalmente esperar que o jogador esteja muito próximo (distância bem curta) para ativar sua animação de surpresa.

Comment: O objetivo do objeto azul é mesmo isso que você falou, animar somente quando o inimigo realmente entrar em cena e também para pegar o player de surpresa, por exemplo, no prefab que mostrei acima, a "flor" sai de trás do cano quando o player atingi o objecto azul, porém há um terceiro que não mencionei (me esqueci), que é executar a movimentação somente se o player passar por uma área específica e assim só tenho que reposicionar/redimensionar o gameobject azul para onde quero dentro do prefab.

Comment: Bom, então o "objeto azul" é a sua área de threat. Ainda assim, talvez seja vantajoso pra você capturar ambos os eventos (de entrada e saída), fazendo-o ser mais largo - só pra facilitar eventuais necessidades futuras. De todas as formas, faz muito sentido você comunicar esses eventos de colisão dele diretamente pro inimigo, e ele se virar com o que tem que fazer a respeito. Como eu disse na sua outra pergunta, usar uma classe genérica pra centralizar esses comportamentos só vai dificultar a sua vida.

Comment: Sim, eu acabei por entender que utilizar uma classe para tudo não seria uma boa solução... vou aplicar o que aqui foi dito, incluindo os 2 triggers mencionados! Entretanto como faço para comunicar ao inimigo que o player entrou na threat area? Aplicando também a solução que está na resposta do Lollipop?

Comment: Sobre o "como faço pra comunicar ao inimigo [...]", eu editei a resposta para adicionar alguns exemplos. Espero que ajude. Boa sorte. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda Luiz!

Answer (score 0):

## O conceito:

`Trigger` em um `child object` para dar `OnTriggerEnter` em um `parent object`.

## O caminho:

Adicione um script para **Objeto Azul** que dar uma referência de script para o **Objeto Rosa**.

## A prática:

Escreva 3 métodos no **Objeto Rosa**`(OnCollisionEnter2DChild, OnCollisionStay2DChild, OnCollisionExit2DChild)` e chame os respectivos métodos `(OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay2D, OnCollisionExit2D)` no objeto **Objeto Azul**, passando o objeto de colisão.